# How to get the root item of a tree item of a QAbstractItemModel?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a `QT5` `TreeModel/TreeView` implementation and I need to get some information of `QAbstractItemModel tree items`

1. Verify if the current item is the root item
2. Who is the root item of a given item.

[image]

For example, in the following tree:

```
- A
- B  
   - B0
   - B1
       - B11
       - B12
   - B2
- C
- D
```

If the current item is `B11`:

1. `B11` is not the root item `(B is the root item)`
2. The `B11` root item is `B`

If the current item is `D`:

1. `D` is a root item
2. `D` doesn't have a root item

I implemented my custom `TreeModel` and in the `data` method I tried to check the two questions I mentioned above. On the `QT` forums I found that `QModelIndex` has a method called `parent()`, but I don't understand how to use it.

```
QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    TreeItem *item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
    auto parent = index.parent();
    qDebug() << "parent: " << parent ;
    return item->data(index.column());
}
```

A long time ago I develop a `QTreeview` project using `TreeWidgetItem` and it was very easy to verify the above questions.

To verify if the current item has a parent:

```
if (!item->parent()) {
   qDebug() << "Root item";
}
```

And to obtain the text of the root item of any child item (or subchild) I use:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* Demo::getParent(QTreeWidgetItem* item) {
    QTreeWidgetItem* parent = item;
    while(parent->parent()) {
        parent = parent->parent();
    }
    return parent;
}

auto rootItem = getParent(item);
qDebug() << "Root node text: " << rootItem->text(0);
```

Do you have any idea to get the same of a `QAbstractItemModel`?

Comment: Have you tried `if (index.parent().isValid()) ...`?

Comment: The *root item* as written in the Qt assistant diagram is the invalid `QModelIndex()`. All the indexes of a model have the same root. What you rather seem to want is one of its direct children, hence the comment from @paddy: is `index.parent()` valid? If not, `index.parent()` is the root item, meaning `index` is a direct child of the root item. I'd personnally go with something like `while (index.parent().isValid()) { index = index.parent(); } return index;` (returns `QModelIndex()` if called with `QModelIndex()`). Hope this is enough of an explanation for you to understand where you got lost.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of:

- [paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553090/paddy)'s comment that suggested to try:

```
if (index.parent().isValid())
```

- [Atmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20143744/atmo)'s explanation:

> The root item as written in the Qt assistant diagram is the invalid `QModelIndex()`. All the indexes of a model have the same root.
>
> What you rather seem to want is one of its direct children, hence the comment from @paddy: is `index.parent()` valid? If not, `index.parent()` is the root item, meaning index is a direct child of the root item.
>
> I'd personnally go with something like:
>
> ```
> while (index.parent().isValid()) { 
>    index = index.parent();
> } 
> return index;
> ```
>
> (returns `QModelIndex()` if called with `QModelIndex()`).

I implemented the following code to verify if an item is a child or the root node:

```
if (index.parent().isValid()) {
  qDebug() << "Child";
} else {
  qDebug() << "Root node";
}
```

The following function will return the root index of any item:

```
QModelIndex TreeModel::getRootIndex(const QModelIndex &index) {
    QModelIndex parentIndex = index;
    while(parentIndex.parent().isValid()) {
        parentIndex = parentIndex.parent();
    }
    return parentIndex;
}

auto rootIndex = getRootIndex(index);
auto rootText = rootIndex.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString(); // to get the text of the root node
```