# Is there an easy way to disable all children of a TreeItem when it is unchecked in a QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt

I wonder if there is an easy way to disable all the children of a `TreeItem` of a `QTreeView/QAbstractItemModel` project when its checkbox is unchecked, perhaps using `Qt::ItemFlags`. And also to change the color of disabled elements with `QBrush(Qt::lightGray)`.

The behavior I would like to implement is as follows:
If any `TreeView` node is `unchecked`, disable all its children and subchildren.

```
- A
   - A0
   - A1
       - A11
       - A22
            - A221
- B
  - B0
```

for example:

if `A1` is `unchecked` then disable `A1`, `A11`, `A22` and `A221`

if `A` is `unchecked` then disable all childrens

This is the `flags` method I'm using

```
Qt::ItemFlags TreeModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags = Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;

    if ( index.column() == 0 )
        flags |= Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;

    return flags;
}
```

I' don't know if this is a feature of `QAbstractItemModel`/`TreeView` that already exists. Any idea or suggestion?

Btw, I'm using `Qt5`.

Comment: similar feature of qtreewidget :```Qt::ItemIsAutoTristate``` .
if use qtreeview, implement it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same approach as in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76018559/20143744) I helped you build a few days ago, simply visit the parents of the index you are looking at and get their data.

```cpp
Qt::ItemFlags TreeModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;


    Qt::ItemFlags flags = Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
    QModelIndex parentIndex = index.parent();
    while(parentIndex.isValid()) {
        if (parentIndex.data(Qt::CheckStateRole).value<Qt::CheckState>() == Qt::Unchecked) {
            flags &= ~Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
            break;
        }
        parentIndex = parentIndex.parent();
    }

    if (index.column() == 0 )
        flags |= Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;

    return flags;
}
```

This assumes only indexes at column 0 have children, which is by far the most common case.
You will have to use `parentIndex.sibling(0, parentIndex.row).data(Qt::CheckStateRole)` otherwise.